# Bound Hypergeometric distribution by Gauss distribution

Tags: combinatorics, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

I want to lower bound the pdf of a Hypergeometric distribution $H(N,K,K)$, which has equal number of success states and number of draws with the pdf of a normal distribution. With the central limit theorem we know that the Hypergeometric function converges to a Gaussian, but can it also be bounded in the non-asymptotic case?
Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by N, K, K at H(N,K,K)?

Comment: According to the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution the three parameters:  population size,number of success states in the population, and number of draws

Comment: Notation with two uppercase K is misleading. It should be somerhing like $H(k, n, K, N)$